# How to use Regex in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I need some help , I have an output from a command and need to extract only the time i.e.  "`10:57:09`" from the output.

The command is:  `tail -f /var/log/sms`

command output:

```
Thu 2016/08/04 10:57:09 gammu-smsd[48014]: Read 0 messages
```

how could I do this in perl and put the result into variable

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perl code:

```
$txt = "Thu 2016/08/04 10:57:09 gammu-smsd[48014]: Read 0 messages";
$txt =~ /(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/;
print $1;  # result of regex
print "\n"; # new line
```

And it prints:

```
10:57:09
```

The result goes to a variable called `$1`, due to the capturing parenthesis. Had there been more capturing parenthesis their captured text would have put int `$2`, `$3` etc...

**EDIT**

To read the line from console, use in the above script:

```
$txt = <STDIN>;
```

Now, suppose the script is called `myscript.pl`, execute `tail` like so:

```
tail -f /var/log/sms | myscript.pl
```

Comment: it works ....i need just more thing how coud i execute tail -f /var/log/sms into script perl to get the txt ??

Comment: @wael: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38762344/7231). But really, this is all pretty basic stuff. Have you read any [Perl books](http://learn.perl.org/books/) or taken any [Perl tutorials](http://perl-tutorial.org/) before trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we'd expect you to show some evidence of trying to solve the problem yourself before giving an answer.

You use the match operator (`m/.../`) to check if a string matches a regular expression. The `m` is often omitted so you'll see it written as `/.../`. By default, it matches against the variable `$_` but you can change that by using the binding operator, `=~`. If a regex includes parentheses (`(...)`) then whatever is matched by that section of the regex is stored in `$1` (and `$2`, `$3`, etc for subsequent sets of parentheses). Those "captured" values are also returned by the match operator when it is evaluated in list context.

It's always a good idea to check the return value from the match operator, as you'll almost certainly want to take different actions if the match was unsuccessful.

See [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) for more details of the match operator and [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more details of Perl's regex support.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

$_ = 'Thu 2016/08/04 10:57:09 gammu-smsd[48014]: Read 0 messages';

if (my ($time) = /(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/) {
  say "Time is '$time'";
} else {
  say 'No time found in string';
}
```

And to get the data from your external process...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

open my $tail_fh, 'tail -f /var/log/sms |' or die $!;
while (<$tail_fh>) {
  if (my ($time) = /(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/) {
    say "Time is '$time'";
  } else {
    say 'No time found in string';
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this script but it stuck .. doesn't show any result

Comment: You're right. My code was too simplistic. Fixed now.